# Почему блоки накладываются друг на друга и пропадает текст?

Tags: html, css, position

У меня должно быть три блока, которые идут за другом. Внутри каждого из них – блок с текстом.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что получается у меня – отображается только один блок, текста вообще нигде не видно:

```css
.groups_line {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-left: 40px;
}

.line {
    width: 519px;
    height: 360px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.line:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.first_group {
    background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/L8tyDfNC/13-2x.png);
}

.second_group {
    background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/QNRGnQJh/kaboompics-com-Woman-preparing-a-lunch-on-the-kitchen-table.png);
}

.third_group {
    background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/76fdKhC5/photo-1453822858805-7c095c06011e.png);
}

.border {
    position: absolute; 
    width: 466px;
    height: 134px;
    border: 3px solid #b59f5b;
    top: 170px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="groups_line">
        <div class="first_group line">
            <div class="first-group-line border">
                <p class="group_line heading">beauty   health  lifestyle</p>
                <p class="group_line text">FROM GRAPEFRUIT TO LEMONS TO ORANGES, CITRUS DOES YOU GOOD!</p>
                <p class="group-line data">June 14, 2015</p>
                <div class="group-line comment_logo">
                    <p class="group-line number">24</p>
                    <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="second_group line">
            <div class="second-group-line border">
                <p class="group_line heading">health</p>
                <p class="group_line text"></p>
                <p class="group-line data"> </p>
                <div class="group-line comment_logo">
                    <p class="group-line number"></p>
                    <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="third_group line">
            <div class="third-group-line border">
                <p class="group_line heading"></p>
                <p class="group_line text"> </p>
                <p class="group-line data"> </p>
                <div class="group-line comment_logo">
                    <p class="group-line number"></p>
                    <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Также [ссылка](https://codepen.io/Van245/pen/OJNdKOq?editors=1100) на codepen

Comment: проверьте кол-во открывающих и закрывающих `<div>` - одного `</div>` не хватает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пропустили закрывающий тэг для `<div class="group-line comment_logo">` в первом и втором блоках.
Правильно должно быть так:

```html
<div class="groups_line">
        <div class="first_group line">
            <div class="first-group-line border">
                <p class="group_line heading">beauty   health  lifestyle</p>
                <p class="group_line text">FROM GRAPEFRUIT TO LEMONS TO ORANGES, CITRUS DOES YOU GOOD!</p>
                <p class="group-line data">June 14, 2015</p>
                <div class="group-line comment_logo">
                    <p class="group-line number">24</p>
                    <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="second_group line">
            <div class="second-group-line border">
                <p class="group_line heading">health</p>
                <p class="group_line text"></p>
                <p class="group-line data"> </p>
                <div class="group-line comment_logo">
                    <p class="group-line number"></p>
                    <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="third_group line">
            <div class="third-group-line border">
                <p class="group_line heading"></p>
                <p class="group_line text"> </p>
                <p class="group-line data"> </p>
                <div class="group-line comment_logo">
                    <p class="group-line number"></p>
                    <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```